# Spring MVC - Thymeleaf th:action th:object

Tags: spring-mvc, binding, thymeleaf

I am using Spring MVC and Thymeleaf.
My template looks like this at the form tag:

```
<form method="post" class="from-group">
</form>
```

It's works, but without `th:action` `th:object`.
I liked this so much (very simple), but I did not find any explanation about this.

How does it work without th:action and th:object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you click submit button it will redirect to the current page you are on if you don't include `th:action`. eg: if `th:action="home"`, it will redirect you to ../home  when you submit the form. `th:object` is sort of what kind of object you want to response. eg: an object called 'person', which it has Name, Sex, DOB, ect. You do not need to use it.